# Matrix from Rectangle and Parallelogram

Tags: c#, wpf, math

System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix has a very handy constructor

```
public Matrix(RectangleF rect, PointF[] plgpts)
```

Basically you can give a rectangle and a parallelogram of the transformed rectangle and you get the corresponding transformation back. In my case, this is very helpful.

Unfortunatly I need the matrix in double precision. 
Does anyone know how I can compute a System.Windows.Media.Matrix from a rectangle and the parallelogram?

Answer (score 0):

This involves some math:

you need to compute a transformation Matrix between 2 bases.

First, compute the basis Vectors of the Rectangle , then the basis Vectors of the parallelogram.

You can then use for example Gaussian elimination to compute the transformation Matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: should be better if you explain how to do it, instead of link to another site :)

Answer (score 0):

blake's answer is correct, however it can be computed a bit easier, since you have a simple rectangle.

You look for a 3x3 matrix which has three column vectors c1, c2 and c3. c1 is the image of (1,0,0), c2 the image of (0,1,0) and c3 the image of (0,0,1).

(0,0,1) is the origin. You can place it at the bottom left corner of the rectangle. So c3 is the bottom left corner of the parallelogram.

(1,0,0) is the direction of the x-axis with length 1. So, c1 is the difference vector of the bottom right corner and the bottom left corner of the parallelogram divided by the width of the rectangle.

Equally for (0,1,0). So, c2 is the difference vector of the top left corner and the bottom left corner of the parallelogram divided by the height of the rectangle.

I should add that you will have to add 0 as the third component for c1 and c2 and 1 for c3.